# 401 error while sending a message into a chat with microsoft teams Graph

Tags: reactjs, axios, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a scenario for sending notification into a chat window from my microsoft teams custom tab.
So, I am trying to call Microsoft Graph API for sending message into a specific chatId: Post [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/${chatId}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/$%7BchatId%7D/messages)
I can get access_token successfully , but while calling post request for sending notification into a chatId , I get "401 UnAuthorized" error .
what is wrong with my code?

```
var message = {
            "body": {
                   "content": "Hello World"
                }
               };
                    fetch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/${context.userObjectId}/chats/${chatId}/messages`, {
                        method: "POST",
                        mode: "cors",
                        cache: "no-cache",
                        headers: {
                           
                            'Content-Type': "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                            'Authorization': `Bearer ${fetched_accessToken}`
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(message)
                    }).then((response) => {
                         alert(response.statusText);
                    }).catch((err) => {
                       alert(err);
                    });    
                }
```

what is wrong with this code?

Comment: I tried to use FormData as the body, but I got "Network error"
   let data = new FormData();
        data.append('client_id', 'xxxxx');
        data.append('scope', 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default');
        data.append('client_secret', 'xxxx');
        data.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');

Comment: well, I could fetch the access_token , by calling the body parameters in deferent way:
const data =  "client_id=xxxxxx&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&client_secret =xxxxxxx&grant_type=client_credentials";
but still I get 404 (Unauthorized) error while posting the message into chat window

Comment: I see that you're trying to use Client Credential flow(application permissions), but the above API call will only work the delegated permissions. It's "by design" and designed to work in that way only. Hence you're seeing the error. You can try the above API call with delegated permissions and you will see it will work. Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

Comment: Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Teams app already, for your tab, and you want to ALSO communicate into the chat, you should look into creating a bot, and using Proactive messaging. See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging

Comment: Cool that's a nice option @Hilton!!

Comment: thanks - it should work well for this scenario, I'd think

Comment: Thanks @HiltonGiesenow, I am not sure when  bot should be installed? In my scenario, there is a chat conversation, then I am adding a new custom tab for that user. The new tab, has some fields for calling third party API, then I need to send a notification into the user in chat window, I thought that I need to use Microsoft graph, by posting into https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/${chatId}/messages. Do you think it is not correct?

Comment: It's possible to post to the chat that way, but that endpoint only supports 'delegated' permssion. As a result, your message would appear to come from that user, rather than from "an app". You also need to deal with the sign in and consent process, to get the token the first time. All of that can be removed, if you have a bot that's part of the app, and the user would add the "app" to the chat - both the Tab AND the Bot would get added at the same time.

Comment: If you want to see an example app in the store that does this, try out "Quicklinks" - it will add a tab of shared links to the chat (or channel) as well as adding a Bot to the conversation at the same time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: sure, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

- I see that you're trying to use Client Credential flow(application permissions), but the above API call will only work the delegated permissions. Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). So it's "by design" and designed to work in that way only. Hence you're seeing the error.
- You can try the above API call with delegated permissions and you
  will see it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have added several permission (both Application and delegated) exp: [Chat.ReadWrite(Delegated),ChatMessage.send(Delegated),Group.Read.All(Application),User.Read,User.ReadWrite,User.ReadWrite.All,User.Read.All,...] But still I get 401 error while trying to send a message to the chat window